# Extracting two map elements with the largest distance in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to extract two elements of a map with the largest distance. For that, I defined the function for calculating the distance and can obtain the distance between the first element (p1) and other elements of the map. But I need to calculate distances between the second item (p2) and the next ones (p3, p4, p5), the third item (p3) and (p4, p5), the fourth item (p4) and fifth item (p5). Then I need to identify the maximum amount between all distances and return the 2 items with the largest distance and the distance itself. Any help is highly appreciated.
Here is my code:

```clj
(defn eclid-dist
  [u v]
  (Math/sqrt (apply + (map #(* % %) (mapv - u v)))))


(def error
  {:p1 [1 2 3]
   :p2 [4 5 6]
   :p3 [7 8 9]
   :p4 [1 2 3]
   :p5 [6 5 4]})


(dotimes [i (dec (count error))]
  (let [dis (eclid-dist (second (nth (seq error) 0))
                        (second (nth (seq error) (+ i 1))))
        max-error (max dis)]
    (println [':dis' dis ':max-error' max-error])))
```

I tried to save each calculated distance as a vector element separately to prevent overwriting but it was not successful.

Comment: Random site note: `'` is used for symbols and not for strings. `':dis'
dis` is not a string and the value of `dis`, but two symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) macro for this. It let's you combine two nested loops to test for all pairs. Then you can use [`max-key`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/max-key) to pick the pair with largest distance:

```
(defn find-largest-dist-pair [vec-map]
  (apply max-key second
         (for [[[k0 v0] & r] (iterate rest vec-map)
               :while r
               [k1 v1] r]
           [[k0 k1] (eclid-dist v0 v1)])))

(find-largest-dist-pair error)
;; => [[:p3 :p4] 10.392304845413264]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rulle. It works great and is quite concise. I am trying to understand what happens inside for macro. My understanding is that It first executes (iterate rest vec-map) which gives us:({:p1 [1 2 3], :p2 [4 5 6], :p3 [7 8 9], :p4 [1 2 3], :p5 [6 5 4]}
 ([:p2 [4 5 6]] [:p3 [7 8 9]] [:p4 [1 2 3]] [:p5 [6 5 4]])
 .........
then takes the first vector and its key as [k0 v0] which is [:p1 [1 2 3]] and all others as r. while there is something in r, it continues. But r should be just one vector at a time. Would be great if you can help me to understand its detail.

Comment: @ZGI Yes, you have understood `for` correctly. You can look at the documentation of `for` (https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for): There are *lots of* examples there that you can try out in the REPL to get a sense of how `for` works.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with `eclid-dist`, you could just use the dedicated Clojure library `clojure.math` (and `->>` thread-last macro for better readability) and rewrite it like this:

```
(:require [clojure.math :as m])

(defn distance [u v]
  (->> (mapv - u v)
       (mapv #(m/pow % 2))
       (reduce +)
       m/sqrt))
```

Your main problem is, how to create unique pairs of points from your data. You could write a recursive function for this:

```
(defn unique-pairs [point-seq]
  (let [[f & r] point-seq]
    (when (seq r)
      (concat (map #(vector f %) r)
              (unique-pairs r)))))

(def error {:p1 [1 2 3]
            :p2 [4 5 6]
            :p3 [7 8 9]
            :p4 [1 2 3]
            :p5 [6 5 4]})

(unique-pairs (vals error))
```

or use library `clojure.math.combinatorics`:

```
Dependency: [org.clojure/math.combinatorics "0.1.6"]
(:require [clojure.math.combinatorics :as combi])

(combi/combinations (vals error) 2)
```

Note that these functions have slightly different results- it doesn't affect the final result, but if you can, you should use `combinations`.

Now, you have to compute `distance` for all these pairs and return the pair with the largest one:

```
(defn max-distance [point-map]
  (->> (combi/combinations (vals point-map) 2)
       (map (fn [[u v]] {:u u :v v :distance (distance u v)}))
       (apply max-key :distance)))

(max-distance error)
=> {:u [1 2 3], :v [7 8 9], :distance 10.392304845413264}
```